# Lat Lon Digitize tool not working with MULTIPOINT in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, tools, qgis-3

I don't know what is a reason but in QGIS 3.2 "**Lat Lon Digitize**" tool doesn't work with **MULTIPOINT**, it works only with **POINT** layers.

Is it a bug?

[image]

Comment: Did this tool work with multipoint layers in a previous version of QGIS?

Comment: I know that a situation is the same with 2.18, but 2.18 (unlike 3.2) has another plugin [Numerical Digitize tool](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/numericalDigitize/), so in 3.2 now it is impossible to add in MULTIPOINT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed on 2018-08-01 for both QGIS 2 and QGIS 3.